# Spring Boot with Spring Security app calls login controller when loading home page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Security. At the basic level it pretty much matches the one from Spring's tutorial. My question is, when I hit the home page, it calls the login controller (twice). Why? It's not readily apparent that it does so with the basic setup, since it just shows the home page. But if I add a LoginController class, it gets called (twice) when loading the home page. Another way to see this is to add an invalid thymeleaf tag to login.html templage, it'll throw an error, even though the home page is not supposed to be authenticated. Any explanation would be of help.

My code:

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

HomeController:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHomePage(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Optional LoginController, will get called when hitting the home page:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLoginPage(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you confirm that the login controller was called twice when you loaded the home page? From the logs? (if so, can you share the logs).

Comment: put a breakpoint, or just a print statement... it actually gets called once, there must've been something in my html that caused it to get called twice, but now it gets called once.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add the a `RequestMapping` in the `LoginController`.

But why would you have a `HomeController` and a `LoginController` when you already have those mappings in `addViewControllers` ?

Comment: sorry, bad formatting... corrected it. still, the question is, why does login controller get called, and even more importantly, why does it render login.html template (or seems to be doing so, and twice)?

Comment: maybe that has to do with whatever link that you have in your login/home template. for example you could have a link to an image/js/css file which are blocked by your security config.

Comment: for testing, my home template is just <html></html>

Comment: but even if the home page had links to restricted pages, why would spring call login controller before those links were ever clicked?

Comment: if it were css/image/js links, its automatically called by you html page. but since they are restricted it is call the login controller. if you have links to others page (no static page), you should be fine